# Como puedo llamar una función

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

hola quisiera saber como puedo utilizar el valor de la variable slider_id que esta en **idit(respon)** pasar lo  a la otra función llamada ***config_slider(slider_id)*** este es el código  ¿como lo puedo hacer?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 
  $('.slideshow').click(idit);

  //funcion para agarrar id

  function idit(respon){
   
  //aqui es donde se pone el valor del id que se agarro  

  let slider_id = $(this).attr('slider');
  console.log(slider_id);

  }
  idit(respon);

  alert(slider_id);

  //funcion del slider
  function config_slider(slider_id){



   var imgPos = 1;
   var imgItems = $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').attr('num'); // Numero de Slides
   //var slider_id = 4;//aqui va el id
   
     

   // Agregando paginacion --
   for(i = 1; i <= imgItems; i++){ 
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination').append('<li ><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></li>');
   } 
   //------------------------#CD6E2E

   
   //$('.agg_id').click(img);

   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').hide(); // Ocultanos todos los slides
   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li:first').show(); // Mostramos el primer slide
   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li:first').css({'color': '#3C8DBC'}); // Damos estilos al primer item de la paginacion


   // Ejecutamos todas las funciones
 
   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li').click(pagination);
   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.right svg').click(nextSlider);
   $('#slider'+slider_id+'.left  svg').click(prevSlider);
   
   
   // FUNCIONES =======================================================


   function pagination(){
       var paginationPos = $(this).index() + 1; // Posicion de la paginacion seleccionada

       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').hide(); // Ocultamos todos los slides
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li:nth-child('+ paginationPos +')').fadeIn(); // Mostramos el Slide seleccionado

       // Dandole estilos a la paginacion seleccionada
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li').css({'color': '#858585'});
       $(this).css({'color': '#3C8DBC'});

       imgPos = paginationPos;

   }

   function nextSlider(){
       if( imgPos >= imgItems){imgPos = 1;} 
       else {imgPos++;}

       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li').css({'color': '#858585'});
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li:nth-child(' + imgPos +')').css({'color': '#3C8DBC'});

       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').hide(); // Ocultamos todos los slides
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li:nth-child('+ imgPos +')').fadeIn(); // Mostramos el Slide seleccionado

   }

   function prevSlider(){
       if( imgPos <= 1){imgPos = imgItems;} 
       else {imgPos--;}

       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li').css({'color': '#858585'});
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.pagination li:nth-child(' + imgPos +')').css({'color': '#3C8DBC'});

       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').hide(); // Ocultamos todos los slides 
       $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li:nth-child('+ imgPos +')').fadeIn(); // Mostramos el Slide seleccionado
   }   
    
}

config_slider(slider_id);


return false

});
```

**esta parte no tiene relevancia**

Esta parte no es relevante nada mas lo pongo por que me dice que es solo codigo y tengo que ponerle texto y bueno tengo que al parecer ponerle mas detalles porque es puro código como que tengo que escribir todo un libro para poder publicar en esta pagina por que siempre es lo mismo con el codigo y sigue con el mismo problema es mas fastidioso acada rato lo mismo

Comment: Por favor no coloques texto de relleno que no aporta nada a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero pon la variable en localStorage

```
let slider_id = $(this).attr('slider');
localStorage.setItem('sliderId', slider_id);
console.log(slider_id);
}

config_slider();
```

Acceso a la variable

```
function config_slider(){

   let slider_id = localStorage.getItem('sliderId')

   var imgPos = 1;
   var imgItems = $('#slider'+slider_id+'.slider li').attr('num'); // Numero de Slides
   //var slider_id = 4;//aqui va el id
```

Aun así creo que deberías crear la variable global y asunto arreglado:

```
let slider_id=-1;

$(document).ready(function(){

 
  $('.slideshow').click(idit);

  //funcion para agarrar id

  function idit(respon){
   
  //aqui es donde se pone el valor del id que se agarro  

 slider_id = $(this).attr('slider');
  console.log(slider_id);

  }
  idit(respon);

  alert(slider_id);

  //funcion del slider
  function config_slider(slider_id){



   var imgPos = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo mucho la pregunta, pero imagino que quieres saber el valor de la variable slider_id del último click realizado en ".slideshow".
El problema es que has declarado la variable slider_id dentro de la función idit con let, de esta forma esa variable solo está disponible dentro de la función. Quítale el let y la variable se convierte en variable global y la tendrás disponible en cualquier sitio.

Un saludo.